# Printing the column names using the output of "df -h" (macOS)

Tags: shell-script, awk, disk-usage

I am trying to:

Print the output of the command "df -h" (in macOS),but only with  /dev/disk* as ouptut. I used the following command:

```
df -h|awk -F"\t" '/\/[d-v]{3}\/[a-z]{4}[0-9]{1}[s-t]{1}[0-9]{1}/{print}'|uniq -c
```

[image: Output from the command]

The original output of command df-h contains the column headers such as "FileSystem ,size,used etc."I trying to achieve the same via the code.

Answer (score 1):

you almost manage it

```
awk 'NR==1 { print ; } /your code/ {print ;}
```

where

- `NR==1 { print ;}` will instruct awk to print first line (**N**umber of **R**ecord == 1 )

Answer (score 1):

```
df -h|awk 'NR==1 || /\/dev\/disk/ {print}'|uniq -c
```

This prints the first record (denoted by `NR`, which is the header) and then any lines matching `/dev/disk`. The `||` means "or".